# Suppress logging in SwaggerGen

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

We are using swagger code gen to generate Java REST API clients from swagger defintiions.

During the gradle builds, we see lot lines like below getting printed in console:

***Is there a way to set log level for swagger gen so that we do not print these INFO and other DEBUG messages during builds?***

```
...
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /project/build.out/swaggerJerseyClient/src/main/java/com/test/RFC3339DateFormat.java
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /project/build.out/swaggerJerseyClient/.swagger-codegen-ignore
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /project/build.out/swaggerJerseyClient/.swagger-codegen/VERSION
...
```

Gradle task looks like below:

```
task swaggerClient(dependsOn: configurations.swagger, type: JavaExec) {
    ext {
        restapi = "$projectDir/swagger.json"
        output = "$build.out/swaggerJerseyClient"
    }

    inputs.file file(restapi)
    outputs.dir output
    classpath = configurations.swagger
    main="io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen"
    args = [
           "generate",
           "-i", restapi,
           "-o", output,
           "-l", "java",
           "--invoker-package", "com.test",
           "--api-package", "com.test.api",
           "--model-package", "com.test.model",
           "-DsupportJava6=true",
           "-DdateLibrary=joda",
           "-Dlibrary=jersey2"
          ]
    doFirst {
        delete output
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the logback configuration or equivalent?

Comment: @DroidX86 I am not sure how to do that.  Thats why I asked the question here.  I am using swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar

Comment: look for a file `logback.xml` in your classpath

Comment: I did not have a logback.xml in my classpath.  I have only the  swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar in classpath.   I created a sample logback.xml and added the directory where the file is present to classpath.  So far it has no effect on build output.